# Problems binding an app to a service with AIDL

Tags: java, android, aidl

I've researched everywhere to solve this problem, and I am fairly certain that it has to do with my manifest file. When trying to connect with the code below with
`contextService = IContextInterface.Stub.asInterface(service)`, the code prints to the log indicating that the service object is still null

```
contextServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            contextService = IContextInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Context Service Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Log.d("IApp", "Binding is done - Context Service connected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            contextService = null;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Disconnected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("IRemote", "Binding - Location Service disconnected");
        }
    };
    if (contextService == null) {
        Intent contextIntent = new Intent();
        contextIntent.setPackage("com.example.the_f.myapplication");
        contextIntent.setAction("service.contextFinder");
        bindService(contextIntent, contextServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mContextIsBound = true;
        if(contextService==null)
            Log.d("locService","NULL");
    }
```

I even check it a second time, so that if its null it will try to manually bind to it. however it is still hitting the last if statement because the log is printing the "locService: NULL".

Here is my client application manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and here is my remote service manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyMiddleware"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
</application>
```

ive restarted this program 3 times because i kept thinking it was building incorrectly or there was a problem in some file buried somewhere. im not really an android pro so im not knowledgeable on many things. any help or guidance would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: You have to wait onServiceConnected.

Comment: ok youre right. i dropped a print statement into onServiceConnected and its not being called. im not sure what im doing different. Ive pretty much copied the various examples ive seen online. even on the android dev site, they have it set up this way. so apparently my app is never connecting to the service

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted I can see one thing missing.
You are setting an action on intent

```
contextIntent.setAction("service.contextFinder");
```

However, you have not defined any filter on the service manifest entry.

Try the following -

```
<service
    android:name=".MyMiddleware"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="service.contextFinder" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Also you do not necessarily need it but if you want to restrict the intent to just your service make sure the package is that of the **service app**.

```
contextIntent.setPackage("com.example.the_f.myapplication");
```

as [natario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4288782/natario) said, you will only get the stub instance in onServiceConnected() callback, not before, almost definitely not right after bindService() call.

Hope this helps.